# What is under the hood of x = y = z in Python?

Tags: python

I came across something like this in python and not sure how to understand this code:

```
somedict['some_key'] = some_val = form.some_field.data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x = y = z` is equivalent to `x = z; y = z` (yes, in that order), except that `z` is evaluated only once.

Or, in terms of Python “compiled” code:

```
>>> compiled_code = compile("x = y = z", filename='con', mode='single')
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(compiled_code)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (z)
              2 DUP_TOP
              4 STORE_NAME               1 (x)
              6 STORE_NAME               2 (y)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: If you just add a link to [the ref docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements) this would cover everything there is to cover in just a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

`somedict['some_key'] = some_val = form.some_field.data`

this is the same thing as:

```
some_val = form.some_field.data
somedict['some_key'] = some_val
```

order normally doesn't matter because only the one on the right can be something un-assignable like a method call, lambda call, keyword, etc...

some places I have seen this used in practice is something like:

`new, assigned, complete = all_modes = "new assigned complete".split()`

Comment: The left size can’t be something unassignable—but `spam.eggs()[23]` is perfectly assignable. For that matter,  consider `a[0][0] = b[0][0] = c` when `b[0]` is `a`.

Answer (score 1):

For some semantic contexts, an assignment statement embodies a value, which is the value assigned to the variable on the left of the equals sign.  In this metaphor, you can regard this as

```
x = (y = z)
```

The value of `z` is assigned to `y`; this is *also* the value of the assignment.  *That* is returned as the value of the expression in parentheses, which is then assigned to `x`.

In practice, the compiler simply leaves the value in a register and does a second "store" operation.

Comment: compiler? register? I don't even think about python in those terms at all... even looking at the C api... but you are right about the syntax

Comment: @GradyPlayer Yeah, the compiler in CPython and PyPy compiles to a stack machine, so you can’t just “leave the value in a register”. You _can_ `DUP_TOP` it to put another reference to the value on the stack, but that’s about as close as it gets.